# How can I make two Html input elements visible and accessible when they are stacked/overlapped vertically on each other in HTML?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, z-index

I have two Html input elements overlapping on each other and I would like to have the content of both visible and I would like only the top input editable.How can I achieve that ?
I have tried so many things with z-index.
my .html code

```
            <ion-input clear-input id="city" #cityInput 
            [(ngModel)]="value" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl
              (change)="cityInputChanged(cityInput.value);">
            </ion-input>
            <input id="typeahead" type="text" class="autocomplete" disabled  [(ngModel)]="placeholderValue" />
```

Here is my CSS

```
.autocomplete {
  color: silver;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
  width:100%;
  //bottom:50px;
}
  #corrected-address-city {
      //width: 260px;
      height: 32px;
      z-index: 7;
      position:absolute;
      top:22px;    
    }
```

In this case only the input 'city' is visible and the input typeahead is not.If I swap z-indexes, both the inputs are visible but I couldn't edit the content of input 'city'.Can someone answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two inputs overlapping, and both visible, you could try adding the style :

```
pointer-events: none;
```

To the one that should not be editable. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

As this will only prevent mouse interaction with the input, you also would need to add the attribute :

```
tabindex="-1"
```

to the HTML input element so that a user could not access the input with TAB either.